# Cannot test FB.login to post without submitting app for review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm building a share button that will (on the user's behalf) post some text and a link to my company facebook wall as part of a competition entry.

I need to use the scope 'publish_actions' for this. However facebook won't let me ask for that until my App has been submitted for review. How am I supposed to do that when I don't even know if my code works yet!?

I've tried creating a "test app" version of the app but it still has the same error:

[image: publish error]

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'xxxx',
    xfbml      : false,
    version    : 'v2.0'
  });
};

FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {

    } else {

    }
}, {
    scope: 'publish_actions', 
    return_scopes: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this question. I had run into the same issue and was considering submitting my app for review :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

People listed as Admins, Developers or Testers within the Roles section of your app dashboard can fully test the app, and request any permissions, without submitting it for review.

However, you must have your integration reviewed before launching your app to real people (people not listed in the Roles section) if you want to request the publish_action permission from them. The only permissions which do not require review are public_profile, email and user_friends.

As you're the developer of the app - you should be able to grant yourself publish_actions without any problems.

Comment: You are correct, the dialog came up after, feel foolish for not trying it first! The default option for posting on their behalf is to share with just friends (on my account anyway). If I post as the user on my company wall, will I still be able to use the API to retrieve those page wall posts?

Comment: I Added one developer in Roles Section. But while sharing it says "user cannot post" in authorization page of FB. any idea ?

Comment: true problem , how can you start on developping the app and you don't have the permission to use the publish_actions or any other

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps, I am a little too late with the answer. But posting in the hope that someone else may find this useful.

There is a way of testing permissions before the app is reviewed and approved. Here goes,
1. log in to https://developers.facebook.com/ and go to your app.

2. Create a test app by clicking on the "Test Apps" option in the left menu. The test app will be a replica of your main(production) app.
3. In your test app click on "Roles" click on the Test Users tab at the top. Here you can create test users. If you test using one of these test users, you would be able to test the permissions without the app being reviewed.

Comment: I just did what you said. Added developer in Roles Section. But while sharing it says "user cannot post" in authorization page of FB. any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had better luck creating a test user within the "real" app.

When I tried to create a test user in the Test App, the publish permissions did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning you as a developer of the app sees, letting you know that even though *you* can grant this permission, other users of your app cannot until the app has been reviewed and approved. You should be able to grant this and verify that your code works, before submitting the app for review.

https://developers.intern.facebook.com/docs/apps/review