# How can I use publish_actions for testing without review?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I need to test score's post to facebook but it requires publish_actions permission. I use the last version of Facebook SDK for Unity3D. Is it possible to get publish_actions permission without review of my application? I tried to get this permission using

```
FB.Login( "publish_actions", LoginCallback );
```

But FBResult of LoginCallback always returns error (403 forbidden) when I try to post score. I also tried to use test users of facebook sdk to test it but with no luck (the same problem - 403 forbidden). I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415126/cannot-test-fb-login-to-post-without-submitting-app-for-review) that I as admin can use all permissions without review. But how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the steps you need to do to get more permisions for your development access token:

1. Go to the following URL: 'https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/'
2. From the dropdown near the top, select the application you want to get extended permissions for
3. Click on 'Get Acces Token'
4. Select all the permisions you want (including publish_actions)
5. Copy the access token generated in the text field besides it, and use it inside Unity when it prompts you for an access token.

Hope this sorts it out for you. If any step is not clear, let me know

Comment: This is maybe true but only for your account not for any other account. For any other accounts and if the FB application doesn't have "publish_actions" registered you got "This does not let the app post to Facebook."

Comment: OP said he needed it for testing purpose, so the above works exactly for that.

Comment: Is there any way to get publish_actions permission for a production Facebook Application ? I am trying to register this for a windows desktop application I am developing but they keep rejecting. They want to try it through a web site which I do not need and do not have.