# Facebook permissions don't pop

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an app facebook, and i work with the new sdk!

And...I have some big problem.
With my dev account, there is no problem, but with a lambda account..

The problem is : -My app ask some permissions : publish_stream, read_stream, publish_actions, photo_upload, user_photos and user_status.
When i redirect on the longinUrl, I don't have the pop up permissions. I think, the probleme is here, but why ?

And when i want to post, the SDK send me than the permissions are not granted...
I don't understand..

Here is the code :

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'XXXX',
      'secret' => 'XXXX'
));

  $user=$facebook->getUser();

if ($user==0) {
header("Location: ".$facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
'scope' =>'publish_stream, read_stream, publish_actions, photo_upload, user_photos,         user_status'
)));
else {
        $facebook->api( '/'.$user.'/feed',
'post',
 array(
 'message'         => $_SESSION['msg'],
 ));
 }
```

EDIT : Now, I have a pop up, but :
Facebook say : This app wil only able ton see your profile.

Facebook don't ask to the users the permissions I ask, why ?
I don't understand..

Comment: Are you including the facebook api php file?

Comment: If the user don't have a role on your app you need to get the permissions approved by facebook.

Comment: Hardy -> Yes, it's include.

Comment: WizKid -> What do you mean ? Just for post a message ?

Comment: WizKid -> PS : And i would have the same error than this guys if that was it no ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23415126/cannot-test-fb-login-to-post-without-submitting-app-for-review
But i don't even have this pop up

Comment: "just" for posting a message? that´s highly abusable by spam apps, so of course you have to approve publish permissions ;)

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using the JavaScript SDK for Login on Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.0

This is a much better solution for many reasons:

- It is mostly unaffected by code changes, the SDK will get downloaded from Facebook on page load
- Much better usability, because the user does not get redirected, it´s a popup
- You don´t need PHP

About your solution with PHP: Make sure you are using the latest [PHP SDK (4.x.x)](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) and a Webhost with PHP >= 5.4. About the permissions: `publish_stream` is deprecated, and you should never request read and write permissions (`read_stream`, `publish_actions`) together. `photo_upload` is not needed, `publish_actions` covers that already. And last but not least: `read_stream` will only get approved for Apps on platforms without a native Facebook client. See this thread for more information: [Is there any way to get Facebook read_stream permission using the latest Facebook app review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948271/is-there-any-way-to-get-facebook-read-stream-permission-using-the-latest-faceboo)

That being said, permissions work without approval too, but only for Admins/Devs of the App.

Also, don´t redirect a user immediately when he enters your App, always let him click on some "Login" button and present some information about your App first. That´s not really a requirement from Facebook, but a good advice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer luschn!
After some test, you're right, i only need publish_actions...

I was thinking than i was needed more! Thanks!

For the redirection, that's because, it's places after a formular. (The user will chose some social media for the app)

Mh, so, for publish action, I need the approval from Facebook to publish on user's wall ?
And that's for it than I don't have permissions pop up ?

Thanks for answer!

Comment: no, you will ALWAYS need to authorize the user, of course. but publish_actions only works for any other user if it gets approved.